# LaTeX beamer theme

Tags: beamer

I would like to know the theme of this beamer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a theme like `Luebeck` and change the colour scheme to whatever you like:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Luebeck}

\definecolor{foo}{RGB}{106,141,143}
\usecolortheme[named=foo]{structure}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=foo!80!black}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\subsection{title}  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
\subsection{title}  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{title}
\subsection{title}  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
\subsection{title}  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]